# Python String split alphabet

Tags: python, string, list

So basically is there a way to split a string in python according to the alphabet? For example input should be BWWWBWWBW and the output should be a list like [B,WWW,B,WW,B,W]?

Comment: The answer is: yes.

Comment: What means @MichaWiedenmann is that your queston does not provide any sign of research/try. So it sounds like a "do my job please" question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` in a list comprehension

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'BWWWBWWBW'
>>> [''.join(i[1]) for i in groupby(s)]
['B', 'WWW', 'B', 'WW', 'B', 'W']
```